# JQuery Ajax call is not filling third-party database

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, squarespace, method-call

I'm trying to connect Squarespace forms to an app called Zola. Zola has a CRM to manage customer leads. When someone submits a form from SS we want it to populate a new lead in the CRM automatically. Zola provided us a code, but it's not populating the CRM. However, they say it's written correctly.

I know nothing about JQuery... Am I missing a trigger? Is the input not defined as a submission?

My code is three parts: the Jquery install, the validation they gave me, and the Ajax call they also gave me.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script
  url: "https://secure.zolasuite.com/api2/CRM/ValidateToken/" 
  method: 'POST'
  parameters: '5AD05C3F-5E85-4178-81D1-90DD4C527599'
  return: 'boolean whether token is valid' 
        ></script>

<script
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(‘#SendRequest’).click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://secure.zolasuite.com/api2/CRM/CreateExternalLead/',
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                    input: {
                        'Token': '5AD05C3F-5E85-4178-81D1-90DD4C527599',
                        'FirstName': 'Derek',
                        'LastName': 'Jeter',
                        'Email': 'derek@aol.com',
                        'Phone': '123-567-6780',
                        'Address': '111 Main St.’,
                        'Message': 'In need of lawyer asap',
                }
    })
})
        ></script>
```

Comment: Check the console for errors. You seem to have several syntax issues, but I'd just like to confirm if they are just in the question or actually in your code.

Comment: Yes I updated what I found in the code in my question... just copied that out of Zola's tutorial so I guess that's a sign right off the bat!

Comment: You've misinterpreted the implementation from Zola, hence the syntax issues mentioned (see 1st link: https://www.google.com/search?q=zola+add+crm+manually). However, even after correcting those issues, there are a number of additional challenges when attempting to do this via Squarespace. But before tackling any of that, you must first verify that a request will work at all. Your 'token' validates, but even simple requests return 'false' from Zola. Getting a result of 'true' would be the first step, then we can solve the other challenges: See basic test here: https://reqbin.com/kkmihydt

Comment: @Brandon, thanks for that feedback! Since I have no prior experience with jquery, I'm ignorant to how I misinterpreted the implementation. To get a result of 'true', do I simply need to rework the code until I get it? Or is it an issue on Zola's end?

Comment: The reqbin link is designed to remove your code as a concern and just send a test request to Zola to see how the server responds. Since it's returning "false", I would guess that indicates an issue on Zola's end, or possibly a setting in your account that needs to be enabled (just as a made-up example). Perhaps you can send the reqbin link in a help request to Zola (and even include a screenshot) and see if they can help you. That way, your code is removed as a "variable in the equation". Note that in the reqbin link, you can click on "Content" and test different names in the request data.